# transfer picture with webservice in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, web-services, web

I have some pictures in different folders and I have a web application

the picture path in xml:

```
<docs order="06" doctype_id="06" doctype="personpic"> 
<doc order="01" regdate="2/10/2010 11:43:00 AM"/> 
<doc order="02" regdate="2/10/2010 11:43:00 AM"/> 
<doc order="03" regdate="2/10/2010 11:43:01 AM"/> 
<doc order="04" regdate="2/10/2010 11:43:01 AM"/> 
<doc order="05" regdate="8/11/2012 12:01:26 PM"/> 
</docs>
```

I want to show the pictures to web app with the web service

I don't want to return the path of the picture to the web app.

Answer (score 0):

You can render images in Byte Array Format through web service.

Please refer below link

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15460/C-Image-to-Byte-Array-and-Byte-Array-to-Image-Conv